# How to start Azure VM async using the latest SDK

Tags: java, azure, sdk, virtual-machine

With the latest azure java sdk -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-beta4</version>
```

---

1. How can i create a VM synchronously and monitor progress ?
2. ComputeManagementClient does not support clientId, tenant type auth. It uses Certificate and all.
3. There are no examples anywhere on the internet. There are only sync examples on the github page:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-vm

Please reply back to this. I find that even on Microsoft forums they are not very responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code sample, as reference for you.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.CloudException;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.PowerState;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.VirtualMachine;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

String clientId = "xxxxx";
String domain = "xxxxx";
String secret = "xxxxx";
AzureEnvironment environment = AzureEnvironment.AZURE; 
/* 
 * Or you can use the code `new AzureEnvironment(String authenticationEndpoint, String managementEndpoint, String resourceManagerEndpoint, String graphEndpoint)`, 
 * please see http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/AzureEnvironment.html
 */
AzureTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, environment);
Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC).authenticate(credentials).withDefaultSubscription();
// Get VM instance
String resourceGroup = "xxxx";
String vmName = "xxxx";
VirtualMachine vm = azure.virtualMachines().getByGroup(resourceGroup, vmName);
// Start the VM instance async
vm.start();
// Get the power status of the VM instance by polling
PowerState powerState = vm.powerState();
System.out.println(powerState);
```

For the APIs used in the code above, please refer to the javadocs http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/.

Hope it helps.